# Retrieving data from listbox and show in text box

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I have wrote a project to display the result in textbox by clicking the list in the listbox. So when i click a value in list box, it should retrieve the result & each column from the database should fit into the textbox i created.

I have already wrote some code, but its not working. I need your help

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string s = "select * from recipe";
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from recipe where ('" + ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ing_tx.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    mx_tx.text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    re_tx.text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }
```

I have three columns in Database namely (Ingredients, Methods, Recipe)

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Do you have three columns or tables?

Comment: i have three columns in table

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I Can add in the list. But from listbox, nothing is fetching into textbox

Answer (score 0):

Set the contents of the listbox on the form load and take it out of your SelectedIndexChanged event, also add the Listbox datasource in.

```
// Create the event 
public void Form_Load()
{
   con.Open();
    string s = "select * from recipe";
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from recipe where ('" + ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = <one of your recipe table fields (e.g. Name)>;
    ListBox1.ValueMember = <one of your recipe table fields (e.g. ID);

}

// Set your textboxes
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // These will all provide the same result, you may need to requery the database for your fields based on an ID.
    ing_tx.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    mx_tx.text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    re_tx.text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the Texts of your Textboxes to ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

You should:

```
ing_tx.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ingredients"].ToString();
mx_tx.text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Methods"].ToString();
re_tx.text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Recipe"].ToString();
```

Comment: Nope! Nothing worked Out. The textbox is empty. Result is not fetching.

Comment: Does the query give result? string s = "select * from recipe";

Comment: Yes I get the result. I gave as "select col1,col2,col3 from recipe"

Comment: you have written that your column names are: Ingredients, Methods, Recipe... are they? or are they col1, col2, col3?

Comment: They are Ingredients, Methods, recipe.

Comment: @Ivoros
`recipe_name | ingredients | method (Column Names in Database)

Aloo Curry | Ingredients of Aloo Curry | Method of Aloo Curry (Detailed Rows)
Veg Briyani | Ingredients 2 | Method 2 (Detailed Rows)
Brownie | Ingredients 3 | Method 3 (Detailed Rows)`

So the listbox in design page contains,
Aloo Curry
Veg Briyani
Brownie